# Como fazer o select do mysql pegar dados com restrição de uma lista?

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde galera, no select do mysql tem a opção IN (), que passa uma lista de string, ai ele filtra essa lista no select no where, ex :

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Existiria alguma função que faça isso mas ao contrario? Um != da lista? eu procurei na net e não encontrei nada.

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faillen, utilize o modificador `NOT` antes do IN, desde modo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id NOT IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: Hmm, o site que encontrei não mencionava isso rs, muito obrigado deu certinho, obrigado mesmo